# ZSH: Hide computer name in terminal

Tags: zsh, prompt

How would I hide the computer name in the prompt while using the terminal?

At the moment it shows both username and computer name like so:

[image: iTerm screenshot of user prompt]

It would save some space by removing `anwarchoukah@anwars-mbp`, seeing as I actually know who I am:)

Comment: Ask this question at http://superuser.com/. You have more change for an answer there

Comment: Go to your `~/.oh-my-zsh/themes` folder, open the theme you are using, comment out the line contains `prompt_context` or something similar. Or try to remove `$USER@%m` from the theme file.

Comment: Thx @MaxPeng! You should have made it a full answer...

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Open up `.zshrc`, find the line reading `export PS1` or maybe `export PROMPT`.

Remove the variable that is used for the hostname, could be %m or %M.

[Zsh on Archlinux wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Zsh#Customizing_the_prompt)

You can use colors and also have a prompt (or some information) on the right side.

Comment: by adding this `PS1="%1d %& # "` would show you current working directory

Answer (score 195):

Try to add `export DEFAULT_USER=$USER` to your `.zshrc` file

Comment: Please note, this will hide both user and hostname (the prompt will be empty). This works because prompt will be populated only if DEFAULT_USER variable is different to USER variable, thus setting both to be the same hides the prompt.

Comment: You can use `$USER` instead of `"$(whoami)"`

Comment: Thanks for this hint! Instead of using `$USER` or `whoami` I set it to my normal logged in user and now I only get the user@host when su'd into another account. This is perfect for me!

Comment: For the `fizsh` frontend of ZSH, in the file `~/.fizsh/fizsh-prompt.zsh`, I modified the two lines including `_fizsh_prompt="%n@%m...` to `_fizsh_prompt="%n...`.

Comment: best answer i have been searching for since last 20mins. thanks

Comment: Hmm this doesn't do anything for me.

Answer (score 72):

On MacOS 10.15 Catalina:

1. Open the file **`/private/etc/zshrc`** in a text editor
2. Locate the comment: `# Default prompt`
3. Modify the line that looks like this: **`PS1="%n@%m~ %& # "`**
4. Save the file. You will be prompted to enter a password to save it.
5. Load a new Terminal window.

For example, you can:

- Remove `"%n@%m"` to get rid of both the username and computer name
- Remove `"%n"` to get rid of the user name
- Remove `"%m"` to get rid of the machine name

Comment: You need to use the sudo command to modify the file. I used 'sudo nano /private/etc/zshrc' enter your password and then you'll be able to edit the file in terminal. After you've successfully saved your changes, close your old terminal and start a new one and you will see the changes.

Comment: If you want a minimal terminal username, follow the steps above and in the # Default prompt section below, use the following: PS1="%# "

Comment: by adding this `PS1="%1d %& # "` would show you current working directory

Comment: would be better to do this in `~/.zshrc` =>

`export PS1="apple@apple-pro %1~ %# "`
 => 
then `source ~/.zshrc` to reload your terminal

Comment: this file does not exist on my system.

Answer (score 53):

1. step 1. one your `.zshrc` file by `vim .zshrc`
2. step 2. go to end of your file.
3. Paste this code:

*careful indent again your code*

```
prompt_context() {
  if [[ "$USER" != "$DEFAULT_USER" || -n "$SSH_CLIENT" ]]; then
    prompt_segment black default "%(!.%{%F{yellow}%}.)$USER"
  fi
}
```

---

**EDIT - explaining what this does**

This will remove the machine@user name from the prompt IF:
- you are not logged in as the default user
- you are not in an ssh client shell

For most people, not needed, but if you regularly ssh to other machines and have multiple terminals open (eg remote sys admin type work) then this is extremely useful so when you look at your terminal you know which machine and user you are logged in as inside that terminal.

If you don't need/manage that type of complexity then use one of the other answers to just modify your export PROMPT/PS1 value.

*** WARNING ***

If you are using a custom shell or theme, this might not work and although the prompt will no longer show your computer and username it will keep throwing the error:

```
prompt_context:2: command not found: prompt_segment
```

For example, you can see with this (very popular) [powerlevel9k](https://github.com/bhilburn/powerlevel9k/issues/423) it does not work. This is because the Powerlevel9k theme uses it's own magic and you simply add commands to your ~/.zshrc file to get the same result, eg:

```
POWERLEVEL9K_LEFT_PROMPT_ELEMENTS=(context)
```

More info on that [here](https://github.com/bhilburn/powerlevel9k#customizing-prompt-segments).

Comment: Thanks. Tried hours. Your solution helped me.

Comment: I wanted to remove the host and only show the user, this worked great

Answer (score 16):

I like this approach (on my mac)

put in .zshrc

```
PS1="%n$ "
```

The terminal will look like

username$

Answer (score 13):

Just add `prompt_context() {}` to `.zshrc`

Comment: this is problematic if you logged in as a different user, because you will not know which user you are in right now

Comment: This is actually perfect, because you can still see git branches on terminal, instead of fixing a single value.

Answer (score 11):

Unfortunately none of the `.zshrc` changes worked for me.
Machine : Mac M1, Big Sur 11.4

So this is what worked.

I Navigated to where the ZSH themes were installed, opened my theme, `agnoster` in TextEdit, and modified the configuration where it chooses what do display, which by default is `$username@%m`.

Note : `%m` here is the machine name.

Here is a screenshot of delta. Yellow is what I did, Green is the default setting from [github version](https://github.com/agnoster/agnoster-zsh-theme/blob/master/agnoster.zsh-theme) of `agnoster` theme.

[image]

Voila this worked. Now to me it just displays the machine name, as I intended.

[image]

Hope that helps. Many links and SOF posts only made me click that solution.

Answer (score 4):

Set `DEFAULT_USER` in `~/.zshrc` file to your regular username. You can get your exact username value by executing `whoami` in the terminal.
Something like this:

```
export DEFAULT_USER=username
```

Answer (score 4):

If you are using PowerLevel9k theme, there is a variable `POWERLEVEL9K_CONTEXT_TEMPLATE` that can change the view of your hostname and computer name.

The default option is `%n@%m`,

- %n -> username
- %m -> machine name

to hide hostname:

1. Open the `.zshrc` file using `sudo nano ~/.zshrc`
2. Add the line
   `POWERLEVEL9K_CONTEXT_TEMPLATE="%n"` at the end of .zshrc file
3. Save the file.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this will help you [ Open **Profile** => **Shell** ]

```
PS1="~ $: ";clear;
```

Comment: there is no such option

Answer (score 2):

For hiding the computer name without removing the current directory name instruction.
Add this in .zshrc

```
PS1="%n@ %1~ %# "
```

And run this

```
source ~/.zshrc
```

And restart the terminal!!!

Answer (score 1):

Just add this to your `~/.zshrc` file:

```
export DEFAULT_USER=\`whoami`
```

Answer (score 1):

Install `Oh My Zsh` is the easiest solution for me:

https://ohmyz.sh/

One liner install:

`sh -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.github.com/ohmyzsh/ohmyzsh/master/tools/install.sh)"`

Result:

[image]

Comment: bro come-on! You are using the default theme on OMZ here, which is `robbyrussell` and this theme settings does that change for you. People are wondering for those changes in another theme or without theme!

Comment: hey, i'm not 100% understand, would you care to explain more :)

Comment: Hey no issues mate. I just meant is that, to remove `username@machinename` is a task. Installing OMZ does that automatically for you because it uses a theme, one I mentioned above, and that theme has this property where it hides them for you. But it may be a challenge for other themes in the package. For eg. the one OP has asked is `agnoster`. Nevermind, here is how I achieved a desired change, in Answer below.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Powerlevel10k, then you can run `p10k configure` and configure the output a bit.

My username and computer-name was gone after having gone through it. It feel less hacky, than the other solutions here.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why I can't find a simplified solution.

So here is the simplified one.

Just jump into the themes directory,

```
# ~/.oh-my-zsh/themes
```

Select the theme, as I have been using

```
# vim agnoster.zsh-theme
```

Just remove `%m` to remove and also you can remove the username too.

Once done,
Just run

```
#zsh
```

To reflect the changes, Enjoy :)

Answer (score -2):

Thanks to Wes Bos' amazing video series [Command Line Power User](http://commandlinepoweruser.com/) , I managed to find the answer.. It's pretty simple. Stuff like that is set in the ZSH theme.

Open up `.zshrc`, change the theme from `ZSH_THEME="agnoster"` (which is what I was using) to something else.

Wes Bos has made a lovely theme called [Cobalt2](https://github.com/wesbos/Cobalt2-iterm) which does exactly what I was looking for :)

I've now changed it to `ZSH_THEME="cobalt2"`

Comment: This assumes that you are *using* `ZSH_THEME`, which is not necessary for modifying the prompt.

Comment: I'm a total noob when it comes to the command line, but am trying to learn. Your comment implies there's a better way. Any chance you could expand on it?

Comment: One of the things that a zsh theme does is set the value of the parameter `PS1` (or maybe `PROMPT`; they are synonyms). This value is what is displayed as your main prompt. See `man zshmisc`, especially the section "SIMPLE PROMPT ESCAPES", to see how various special character sequences are displayed when they appear in the value of `PS1`.

Comment: @chepner - that did it – enough for me to know where to start. Thanks!