# What is faroarm-laptop in mac terminal path? myusername@faroarm-laptop ~ %

Tags: macos, terminal

In terminal with Catalina, I'm getting myusername@faroarm-laptop ~ %.  Where is faroarm-laptop coming from? I didn't create any username with that title.  Checked for virtualenvs or anything like that creating the name but found none.

Answer (score 0):

Was able to change the name back to the computers name with this answer.  still not sure exactly where faroarm-laptop name came from...

[ZSH: Hide computer name in terminal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31848957/zsh-hide-computer-name-in-terminal)